# Accessing Structure Elements in a Function

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

when I compile the code below, I'm presented with the errors

```
snippet.c:24:24: error: request for member ‘px’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:25:24: error: request for member ‘py’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:27:22: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:27:45: error: request for member ‘y’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:31:14: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:35:16: error: request for member ‘y’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:39:25: error: request for member ‘px’ in something not a structure or union
snippet.c:40:25: error: request for member ‘py’ in something not a structure or union
```

for the code below

```
struct list{
    int x;
int y;
int f;
int g;
int h;
int px;
int py;
};

void history(int j, struct list *path[], struct list *closelist[], struct list *start, int *fxele);
void history(int j, struct list *path[], struct list *closelist[], struct list *start, int *fxele){

int i, p;

path[0] = closelist[j];
p = 1;

struct list tempsq;

tempsq.x = (*closelist).px[j];
tempsq.y = (*closelist).py[j];

while(tempsq.x=!start.x && tempsq.y =! start.y){

for(i = 0; i <= *fxele; i++){

if(closelist.x[i] = tempsq.x){

    for(j = 0; j <= *fxele; j++){

        if(closelist.y[j] = tempsq.y){

            path[p] = closelist[j];
            p = p+1;
            tempsq.x = closelist.px[j];
            tempsq.y = closelist.py[j];

            }
        }   
    }
}
}

return;
}
```

The code is meant to trace back the parents of squares for a pathfinding system, but the specifics aren't important.  I'm curious as to what is wrong with how I'm calling 'closelist' and 'start' that is preventing me from calling their structure elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These statements

```
tempsq.x = (*closelist).px[j];
tempsq.y = (*closelist).py[j];
```

are wrong.
`px` and `py` are not arrays in your structure. Instead try this

```
tempsq.x = closelist[j].px;
tempsq.y = closelist[j].py;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that "l" is an array of some struct type "list" and "b" is the name of a field within that struct:

```
struct list {
    int b;
};

struct list l[10];
```

If you type:

```
l.b[0];
```

This is incorrect. To get "b" from the first "list" struct in the array, you should type:

```
l[0].b;
```

Since one of the arguments to your function "history" is:

```
struct list *closelist[]
```

this means you are passing a pointer to an array of list structs, so if you want the px and py data members from the j'th struct, you must type:

```
(*closelist)[j].px;
(*closelist)[j].py;
```